# NextJS - Creating a dynamic navbar with a complicated hierarchy of pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am creating a NextJS 13 Typescript project with a complicated hierarchy of pages (pages have subpages, and subpages have subpages, etc). I am trying to create a dynamically updating navbar component as I feel like it would be easier to update in the future instead of trying to manually go through the code and add another subpage.

I have been experimenting in vanilla javascript with arrays such as:

```
const pageHierarchy = 
[
    ["page 1", ["sub-page 1", "sub-page 2", "sub-page 3"], 
    ["page 2", ["sub-page 1", "sub-page 2", "sub-page 3", ["sub-sub-page 1", "sub-sub-page 2"] "subpage4"]], 
    ["page 3"]
]
```

and use the following code to destruct each array into its individual elements:

```
function printArrayItems(arr) {
    arr.forEach(item => {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            printArrayItems(item);
        } else {
            console.log(item);
        }
    });
}
```

which would produce the following output:

```
"page 1"
"sub-page 1"
"sub-page 2"
"sub-page 3"
"page 2"
"sub-page 1"
"sub-page 2"
"sub-page 3"
"sub-sub-page 1"
"sub-sub-page 2"
"subpage4"
"page 3"
```

How would I modify this code to keep track of the page above each sub page in the hierarchy of pages?

Also, please tell me if this is a stupid way to go about creating a complicated navbar. Possibly using dynamic routing, etc. This is my first "big" NextJS project.

Thanks,